# How to make Due Date visible on issue view if null (Jira Software Cloud)

Tags: jira

I am administering a Cloud instance of Confluence, Jira Software, and Jira Service Desk.
In Jira, by default, the Due Date field is only visible on view issue screen if it has a value.  I want the field to display even if blank.  Does anyone know of a workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Jira Server by modifying the source code, but unfortunately this is not possible on Jira Cloud.
If it helps, you can add the due date field to the issue detail view on your board, so it would be quickly accessible from there.